# How to Show Tables using Where clause in H2 SQL?

Tags: sql, h2

I'm using this query to shows table from a schema in h2, but it's not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyqCR.png)

Comment: Hello ,

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Don't think you can add a where clause to a show query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SHOW` command does not implement complex filtering conditions. However, you can run a simple `SELECT` to get your tables:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'PUBLIC' -- your schema
  and table_type = 'TABLE'
  and table_name like '%RU%' -- your custom filtering condition
```